# Weird behaviour while changing the parent of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

my element structure looks something like this (simplified):

```
#Element Holder
    @Element Data
    #Element Holder
        @Element Data
    #Element Holder.
        @Element Data
#Element Holder
    @Element Data
```

Think of it as something of a file structure, where a File/Folder is equal to `#Element Holder` and `@Element Data` is each files/folders style content (icons etc.)

Im trying to move an array of type `@ElementData` to the `Dropzone` element, so far Ive tried versions of this:

```
for(i = 0; i < ElementDataArray.length; i++){
    Dropzone.appendChild(ElementDataArray[i].parentNode)
}
```

but this only works for the first element of the array (other elements stay unchanged).

Im guessing there is something going on in the DOM that Im not aware of, but currently Im just a bit lost

**UPDATE**

As requested by Barmar here is the stack snippet, Im sorry for this code dump, but the simplified version worked as expected, however I have no clue what went wrong here, the part that gives me headaches is located in the `drop` event listener

**How to reproduce the issue:**
run the snippet, CTRL select two or more items of the same type (2+ files or 2+ folders) and drag them into a random folder or the parent directory (gray zone below all the files and folders)

**Current Result:**
only one item is moved, the other items stay unchanged (moved items higlighted with red)

**Expected Result:** All the selected items get transferred

```js
var file_manager = document.getElementById('file-manager')

var dragged;
var dropzone = undefined

var items = []
var dataSet = [{
        "_id": "60f5b94f7e7e030d80888dd4",
        "name": "EEEEE",
        "path": [],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-19T17:41:35.290Z",
        "isFile": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f5e8ac429e454e341534fb",
        "name": "pog",
        "path": [],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-19T21:03:40.888Z",
        "isFile": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f5f7aad1b95b51840e98ca",
        "name": "poem",
        "path": [{
            "name": "pog",
            "_id": "60f5e8ac429e454e341534fb"
        }],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-19T22:07:38.044Z",
        "isFile": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f8ae19a44c7048306fdd8b",
        "name": "New folder",
        "path": [],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-21T23:30:33.580Z",
        "isFile": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f8ae1ba44c7048306fdd8d",
        "name": "new",
        "path": [{
            "name": "New folder",
            "_id": "60f8ae19a44c7048306fdd8b"
        }],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-21T23:30:35.846Z",
        "isFile": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f8b4708a065c4f3c068689",
        "name": "New file",
        "path": [{
                "name": "New folder",
                "_id": "60f8b4718a065c4f3c06868a"
            },
            {
                "name": "new",
                "_id": "60f8ae1ba44c7048306fdd8d"
            },
            {
                "name": "New folder",
                "_id": "60f8ae19a44c7048306fdd8b"
            }
        ],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-21T23:57:36.198Z",
        "isFile": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f8b4718a065c4f3c06868a",
        "name": "New folder",
        "path": [{
                "name": "new",
                "_id": "60f8ae1ba44c7048306fdd8d"
            },
            {
                "name": "New folder",
                "_id": "60f8ae19a44c7048306fdd8b"
            }
        ],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-21T23:57:37.204Z",
        "isFile": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "60f9b4117a7946585c8487ba",
        "name": "New file",
        "path": [{
                "name": "New folder",
                "_id": "60f8b4718a065c4f3c06868a"
            },
            {
                "name": "new",
                "_id": "60f8ae1ba44c7048306fdd8d"
            },
            {
                "name": "New folder",
                "_id": "60f8ae19a44c7048306fdd8b"
            }
        ],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-22T18:08:17.771Z",
        "isFile": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "60fa3abc8612930538c4ecb4",
        "name": "New folder",
        "path": [{
            "name": "pog",
            "_id": "60f5e8ac429e454e341534fb"
        }],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-23T03:42:52.671Z",
        "isFile": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "60fa3ac68612930538c4ecb5",
        "name": "no",
        "path": [],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-23T03:43:02.320Z",
        "isFile": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "6100be61171bce035120d603",
        "name": "mobile test",
        "path": [{
            "name": "no",
            "_id": "60fa3ac68612930538c4ecb5"
        }],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-28T02:18:09.181Z",
        "isFile": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "6100be6f171bce035120d604",
        "name": "mobile test 2",
        "path": [{
            "name": "pog",
            "_id": "60f5e8ac429e454e341534fb"
        }],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-28T02:18:23.676Z",
        "isFile": true
    },
    {
        "_id": "6104088123b899c7bd4ff752",
        "name": "New folder",
        "path": [],
        "dateCreated": "2021-07-30T14:11:13.560Z",
        "isFile": false
    },

]

loadFileManager()

function loadFileManager() {
    file_manager.innerHTML = ''
    items = []
    loop(undefined, 1)

    function loop(parentid, depth) {
        var tmp = []

        dataSet.forEach(item => {
            if (item.path.length > 0) { //sub directory
                if (parentid) {
                    if (item.path[0]._id == parentid) {
                        tmp.push({
                            item: item,
                            depth: depth
                        })
                    }
                }
            } else { //main directory
                if (parentid == undefined) {
                    tmp.push({
                        item: item,
                        depth: depth
                    })
                }
            }
        });

        var folders = tmp.filter(i => i.item.isFile == false)
        var files = tmp.filter(i => i.item.isFile == true)


        folders.forEach(f => {
            create(f.item, f.depth)
            loop(f.item._id, f.depth + 1)
        });
        files.forEach(f => {
            create(f.item, f.depth)
            //loop(f.item.id, f.depth + 1)
        });
    }
}

function create(item, depth) {
    var holder = document.createElement('div')
    var name = document.createElement('span')
    var data = document.createElement('div')

    data.style.textIndent = (20 *depth) + 'px'
    
    if (item.isFile) {
        data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + `
        <svg class="file-icon-svg" width="13" height="15" viewBox="0 0 77 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path  d="M73.5 34.5192V89C73.5 93.1421 70.1421 96.5 66 96.5H11C6.85786 96.5 3.5 93.1421 3.5 89V11C3.5 6.85787 6.85787 3.5 11 3.5H42.751C44.7551 3.5 46.6759 4.30212 48.0848 5.72742L71.3338 29.2466C72.7217 30.6505 73.5 32.5451 73.5 34.5192Z" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="7"/>
        <path  d="M42.875 2V36H75.25" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="7"/>
        </svg>
        `
    } else {

        data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML + `
        <svg class="arrow-icon-svg" width="10" height="5" viewBox="0 0 56 29" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M55.0248 6.02109L28 28.5L24 23.4976L51 1L55.0248 6.02109Z" fill="#CCCCCC"/>
        <path d="M5 1L31.5786 23.6976L28 28.5L0.910334 5.79628L5 1Z" fill="#CCCCCC"/>
        </svg>

        <svg class="folder-icon-svg" width="15" height="20" viewBox="0 0 98 80" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M94 21.3256V71.9437C94 74.1839 92.189 76 89.9551 76H8.04494C5.81098 76 4 74.1839 4 71.9437V8.05634C4 5.81608 5.81098 4 8.04494 4H39.5183C40.5315 4 41.5079 4.38133 42.2541 5.06854L52.6028 14.5979C54.4686 16.316 56.9094 17.2693 59.4423 17.2693H89.9551C92.189 17.2693 94 19.0853 94 21.3256Z" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="7"/>
        </svg>
        `
    }

    name.innerHTML = item.name

    holder.classList.add('file-manager-item', 'noselect', (item.isFile) ? 'file' : 'folder')
    holder.id = item._id
    data.title = item._id

    data.classList.add('file-manager-item-hover')
    data.draggable = true

    data.onclick = function (e) {
        removeClass(file_manager, 'selected-file-manager-item')
        data.classList.add('selected-file-manager-item')
        var nodeDepth = 0

        if(e.ctrlKey){
            if(data.classList.contains('ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')){
                data.classList.remove('ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
                removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed')
                data.classList.add('ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed')
            }
            else{
                removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed')
                data.classList.add('ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
            }
        }
        else{
            getDepth(holder)

            function getDepth(child) {
                if (child != null) {
                    nodeDepth++
                    getDepth(child.parentNode)
                }
            }
    
            nodeDepth = nodeDepth - 6
            
            removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed')
            removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
            data.classList.add('ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')

            if(item.isFile == false) { //folder
                var arrow = data.getElementsByClassName('arrow-icon-svg')[0]
                var arrowStyle = getComputedStyle(arrow).transform
                if (arrowStyle == 'none' || arrow.style.transform == 'rotate(0deg)') { //close folder
                    arrow.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)'
                    if (holder.children.length > 0) {
                        for (i = 1; i < holder.children.length; i++) {
                            holder.children[i].style.display = 'none'
                        }
                    }
                } else { //open folder
                    arrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
                    if (holder.children.length > 1) {
                        for (i = 1; i < holder.children.length; i++) {
                            holder.children[i].style.display = 'block'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    data.ondblclick = function () {
        console.log(item.name + ' [' + item._id + ']')
    }

    data.appendChild(name)
    holder.appendChild(data)

    if (item.path.length == 0) {
        file_manager.appendChild(holder)
    } else {
        document.getElementById(item.path[0]._id).appendChild(holder)
        holder.style.display = 'none'
    }
}

file_manager.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'file-manager') {
        removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
        removeClass(file_manager, 'selected-file-manager-item')
        removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed')
    }
}

document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BODY') {
        removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
        removeClass(file_manager, 'selected-file-manager-item')
        removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed')
    }
}

function windowItemClick(e) {
    for (i = 0; i < windowItems.length; i++) {
        windowItems[i].classList.remove('window-header-item-selected')
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains('window-header-item-close-button')) {
        e.target.parentNode.classList.add('window-header-item-selected')
    } else {
        e.target.classList.add('window-header-item-selected')
    }
}

/* events fired on the draggable target */
document.addEventListener("drag", function (event) {
    removeClass(file_manager, 'selected-file-manager-item')
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function (event) {
    var many = file_manager.getElementsByClassName('ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
    if(many.length > 0){
        var includes = false
        for(i = 0; i < many.length; i++){
            if(many[i] == event.target){
                includes = true
                break
            }
        }

        if(includes){//CTRL
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].children[0].classList.remove('selected-file-manager-item')
            }
    
            dragged = many

            createCoverup(dragged.length)
        }
        else{//CTRL -> DRAG
            removeClass(file_manager, 'ctrl-selected-file-manager-item')
            for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                items[i].children[0].classList.remove('selected-file-manager-item')
            }
            event.target.classList.add('selected-file-manager-item')
    
            dragged = []
            dragged.push(event.target)

            createCoverup(dragged[0].children[dragged[0].children.length - 1].innerText)
        }
    }
    else{//DRAG
        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            items[i].children[0].classList.remove('selected-file-manager-item')
        }
        event.target.classList.add('selected-file-manager-item')

        dragged = []
        dragged.push(event.target)

        createCoverup(dragged[0].children[dragged[0].children.length - 1].innerText)
    }

    function createCoverup(text){
        var coverup = document.createElement('span')
        coverup.innerText = text
        coverup.classList.add('coverup')

        coverup.style.position = "absolute";
        coverup.style.top = "0px";
        coverup.style.right = "-300px";
        document.body.appendChild(coverup);
        event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(coverup, -10, -10);
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragend", function (event) {
    // reset the transparency
    event.target.style.opacity = "";
}, false);

/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
    // prevent default to allow drop
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", function (e) {
    dropzone = undefined
    var found = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY)

    removeClass(document, 'hovered-folder')
    removeClass(document, 'hovered-main')

    if (found.length > 3) {
        for (i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
            if (found[i].classList.contains('folder')) {
                var highlight = true
                for (x = 0; x < dragged.length; x++) {
                    if (dragged[x].parentNode.parentNode == found[i] || dragged[x].parentNode == found[i] || dragged[x].parentNode.contains(found[i])) {
                        highlight = false
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (highlight) {
                    found[i].classList.add('hovered-folder')
                    dropzone = found[i]
                }
                return
            }
        }
    } else if (found[0].id == 'file-manager') {
        for (x = 0; x < dragged.length; x++) {
            if (dragged[x].parentNode.parentNode.id != 'file-manager') {
                found[0].classList.add('hovered-main')
                dropzone = found[0]
                return
            }
        }
    }
}, false);

document.addEventListener("drop", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    file_manager.classList.remove('hovered-main')
    removeClass(file_manager, 'hovered-folder')

    if (dropzone) {
        var depth = 0
        var path = []

        getDepth(dropzone)
        function getDepth(child){
            if(child != null){
                if(child.id){
                    if(child.id != 'file-manager'){
                        var v = dataSet.find(data => data._id == child.id)
                        path.push({"name":v.name, "_id":v._id})
                    }
                }
                depth++
                getDepth(child.parentNode)
            }
        }
        depth = depth - 4

        for(i = 0; i < dragged.length; i++){
            var currentDragged = dragged[i].parentNode

            if(currentDragged.classList.contains('folder')){
                dropzone.insertBefore(currentDragged, dropzone.children[1]);
            }
            else{
                dropzone.appendChild(currentDragged)
            }

            loop(currentDragged, depth + 1)
            function loop(element, currentDepth){
                var tmp = []
                element.children[0].style.textIndent = (20 * (currentDepth)) + 'px'
                element.children[0].style.color = 'red'

                for(x = 1; x < element.children.length; x++){
                    tmp.push(element.children[x])
                }

                tmp.forEach(t => {
                    loop(t, currentDepth + 1)
                });
            }
        }

        var arrow = dropzone.getElementsByClassName('arrow-icon-svg')[0]
        arrow.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)'
        for (x = 1; x < dropzone.children.length; x++) {
            dropzone.children[x].style.display = 'block'
        }

        dropzone = undefined
    }
}, false);

function removeClass(element, classname) {
    let x = element.getElementsByClassName(classname);
    [...x].forEach(x => x.classList.remove(classname));
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

:root {
    color-scheme: dark;
}

.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


.hovered-folder .file-manager-item-hover{
    background-color: #08574F !important;
}

.hovered-main{
    background-color: #08574F !important;
}

/*#region file manager*/
#file-manager{
    width: 300px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 520px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scrollbar-color: #202020 #101010;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    background-color: #101010;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
}
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #101010; 
}
   
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #202020; 
}
  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #353535; 
}

#file-manager:hover .file-manager-line{
    opacity: 1;
}

.file-manager-item{
    background-color: #101010;
    width: 100%;
    font-smooth: always;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;/*disable blue tap highlight*/
}

.selected-file-manager-item{
    background-color: #202020;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #009688; 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #009688;
}

.file-manager-item-hover{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
}

.file-manager-item-hover:hover{
    background-color: #404040;
}

.file-manager-line{
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #333333;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .15s;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.selected-file-manager-line{
    background-color: #585858 !important; 
}      

.file-icon-svg {
    margin-bottom: -2.5px;
}

.file-icon-svg path {
    stroke: #dfdfdf;
}

.folder-icon-svg {
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

.folder-icon-svg path {
    stroke: #dfdfdf;
}

.arrow-icon-svg{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin-bottom: 3px !important;
    margin-left: -12px;
}

.coverup {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;

    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #202020 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #009688; 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #009688;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    font-smooth: always;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
/*#endregion*/

.ctrl-selected-file-manager-item, .ctrl-selected-file-manager-item:hover{
    background-color: #202020;
}

.ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed, .ctrl-selected-file-manager-item-removed:hover{
    background-color: #070707;
}

.test{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/window.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="file-manager"></div>
    <div id="coverup"></div>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `ElementDataArray` really an array? Or is it something like `ElementHolder.children`?

Comment: If it's a `children` list, then when you move an element to a different parent, it's no longer a child of the original holder, so all the indexes after that shift down.

Comment: The solution is to make it a real array: `ElementDataArray = Array.from(ElementHolder.children);`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, its an array of  `@Element Data`, when I log it I get the appropriate result containing  `@Element Data's`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of pasting your update into the original question-- please post updates as edits, not as answers.

Comment: @AlexanderNied thanks for pointing that out, I deleted the post, I will remember to do this next time